# Plotting animated point on a polar plot

Tags: plotting, graphics, animation

How can I animate a point on a polar curve? I have used `Animate` and `Show` together before in order to get the curve and the moving point together on the same plot, but combining the polar plot and the point doesn't seem to be working because point only works with Cartesian coordinates.

Here is the code I used before to animate a point on a parametric curve. For higher values of `a` and `theta`, you can see the point moving along the curve better (I was required to animate all three parameters).

```
Animate[
 Show[
  ParametricPlot[{a Cos[θ] t, a Sin[θ] t - 4.9 t^2}, {t, 0, 15}, AxesLabel -> {"x", "y"},
   PlotRange -> {{0, 50}, {0, 30}}],
  Graphics[{Red, PointSize[.05], Point[{a Cos[θ] t, a Sin[θ] t - 4.9 t^2}]}]
 ],
 {t, 0, 5, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 {a, 1, 20, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 {θ, 0, Pi/2, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 AnimationRunning -> False
]
```

Here is the code I tried to use to animate a point on a polar curve, but the point does not even show up.

```
Animate[
 Show[
  PolarPlot[2 Sin[4*θ], {θ, 0, 2 Pi}],
  Graphics[Red, PointSize[Large], Point[{2 Sin[4*θ] Cos[θ], 2 Sin[4*θ] Sin[θ]}]]
 ],
 {θ, 0, 2 Pi}, 
 AnimationRunning -> False
]
```

Comment: Please include the code you have tried so far, the one you have used before, and we'll go from there.

Answer (score 3):

It is not necessary to resort to `Show`. Your animation can easily be accomplished with `Epilog`.

```
Animate[
  PolarPlot[2 Sin[4 θ], {θ, 0, 2 Pi}, 
    Epilog -> 
      {Red, PointSize[Large], Point[{2 Sin[4 θ] Cos[θ], 2 Sin[4*θ] Sin[θ]}]}],
  {θ, 0, 2 Pi},
  AnimationRunning -> False]
```

Answer (score 3):

Conceptually you are there already; you only had a small syntax error in your code, i.e. **a missing set of braces** around the items in the `Graphics` expression:

```
Animate[
 Show[
  PolarPlot[2 Sin[4*t], {t, 0, 2 Pi}],
  Graphics[{Red, PointSize[0.02], Point[{2 Cos[θ] Sin[4 θ], 2 Sin[θ] Sin[4 θ]}]}]
  ],
 {θ, 0, 2 Pi},
 AnimationRunning -> False
]
```

The problem is more visible if you temporarily comment out the `PolarPlot` expression from your code; the resulting `Graphics` will then complain of an incorrect syntax issue, which is what led me to discover the problem.

As a small improvement, I would suggest that you write your transformed point as:

```
Point[Sin[4 θ] {Cos[θ], Sin[θ]}]
```

This way you can avoid having to rewrite your polar function twice.

Answer (score 3):

```
Animate[PolarPlot[2 Sin[4 θ], {θ, 0, 2 Pi}, Axes -> False, 
            MeshFunctions -> {#3 &}, Mesh -> {{{θ, Directive[Red, PointSize[Large]]}}}], 
       {θ, 0, 2 Pi}, AnimationRunning -> False]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

```
Animate[
 ParametricPlot[f[a, s, u], {u, 0, 15}, 
  PlotRange -> {{0, 50}, {0, 30}}, 
  Epilog -> {Red, PointSize[0.05], Point[f[a, s, t]]}], {a, 1, 
  20}, {s, 0, Pi/2}, {t, 0, 5}, 
 Initialization :> (f[a_, s_, t_] := 
    a t { Cos[s] , Sin[s]} - {0, 4.9 t^2})]
```

[image]

I have not done all the niceties but suggest this suffices to operationalize.

Answer (score 0):

```
Animate[
 Show[
  PolarPlot[Sin[3 t], {t, 0, π}],
  Graphics[{Red, PointSize[0.02], 
    Point[Sin[3 θ] {Cos[θ], Sin[θ]}]}]],
 {θ, 0, π}]
```